# Regex start to end

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex A to allow me to separate the blocks 3 (start:"~0" , end: "~end") and then another regular expression paragraph each separates Block by section (~0 TEXT,~10 TEXT, ~11 TEXT) , the numbers range is from ~0 to ~11.

thx !

My Regex:

```
~\d{1,2} (.*?)\~end$     

~\d0 (.*?)\~end$

[\~1](.*)[\/end]
```

My input

```
    ~0 
    victor
    ~10 
    aaaa
    ~11 
    bbbb
    ~end

    ~0 
    juan
    ~10 
    cccc
    ~11 
    dddd
    ~end 


    ~0 
    maria
    ~10
    eeee
    ~11 
    fffffff
    ~end
```

I need:

1

```
 ~0 
    victor
    ~10 
    aaaa
    ~11 
    bbbb
    ~end
```

2

```
    ~0 
    juan
    ~10 
    cccc
    ~11 
    dddd
    ~end
```

3

```
    ~0 
    maria
    ~10
    eeee
    ~11 
    fffffff
    ~end
```

And next Regex:

victor

aaaa

bbbb

Comment: What output do you want? Or do you just need each of those sections in matching groups? What language are you using?

Comment: the blocks: <pre> ~0 victor ~10 aaaa ~11 bbbb ~end </pre> <pre> ~0 juan ~10 cccc ~11 dddd ~end </pre> <pre> ~0 maria ~10 eeee ~11 fffffff ~end </pre>

Comment: See [`(?ms)^~0.*?\n~end`](https://regex101.com/r/kR8Aj1/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok http://regexr.com/ say error :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse to string to multidimensional array (regex?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266309/how-to-parse-to-string-to-multidimensional-array-regex)

Answer (score 0):

To get all the blocks in separate matches:

Use `~0.*?~end`, with options set for global and single-line

Then, to get all the values without the numbered tags:

Search: `~.*\n` (global, but **not** single-line)

Replace: [nothing]

Comment: ~.*\n  not founf with multiline :/

Comment: @VictorMoscosoLembcke: you mean single-line? The second step (search/replace) should not use single-line. I updated the answer.

Comment: to example

 ~0 
yyyyyyyyyyy
xxxxxxxx
ffffffffff
~1 
rrrrrrrrrrrr 24fdsg dsf45sdf
        ~end

Comment: @VictorMoscosoLembcke: see [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/2U0GWM/1). Is that what you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266309/php-data-parse-to-array-regex better explain (php)